# Does SMTP needs to be separately configured to send mails in Linux?

Tags: linux, unix

One doubt I have is since in my old project whenever we used to write shell scripts on thee server, we just used various mail utilities of linux (sendmail, mail). We never configured any SMTP.

Suppose I have a new server with all these utilities installed, should I worry about configuring smtp?

Comment: I guess you don't need to worry about that as `smtp need not be configured`,but,not that much sure to write an answer!

Comment: This is not a programming question.  You move it to ServerFault, SuperUser or Unix&Linux.

Comment: Why was this question off-topic? and what was so low with the question that it got down rated 3 times.? When we use sendmail package It usually has a built in SMTP or do we have to separately configure it? That was my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you can use typical cli utilities without any configuration required, provided you have sendmail installed (or something compatible) and your network configuration is ok. That is because the responsible server the utility has to use to send the email can be retrieved via DNS lookup.

This is different however if you want to use an outgoing smtp server, then you have to configure which one and how it can be used. This makes a lot of sense, since it allows more fine grained control and can prevent certain unwanted message details getting accepted like for example an invalid sender address. Also it can help improve the acceptance of your message by remote smtp servers which might not always work when your network setup is non-trivial.